# fetching rows that are tagged to one value only using SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table containing two columns content_id and geography_id, there are many content ids that are tagged to more than one geography. How can fetch only those content ids that are tagged to a specific geography and not to any other geography.

TIA,
Ankit

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
select content_id
from the_table
group by content_id
having count(distinct geography_id) = 1
   and max(geography_id) = 126 -- this is the geography_id you are looking for
```

Doing that for two IDs changes the statement slightly:

```
select content_id
from the_table t1
where geography_id in (11,12)
group by content_id
having count(distinct geography_id) = 2
```

If you need to get those region_id's with **exactly** those two geography_id's it's a bit more complicated:

```
select t1.content_id
from the_table t1
where t1.geography_id in (11,12)
group by t1.content_id
having count(distinct t1.geography_id) = 2
   and count(distinct t1.geography_id) = (select count(*) 
                                          from the_table t2
                                          where t2.content_id = t1.content_id)
```

Or as an alternative:

```
select content_id
from the_table
where geography_id = 11
intersect
select content_id
from the_table
where geography_id = 12
minus  -- this would be intersect for any other DBMS
select content_id
from the_table
group by content_id
having count(distinct geography_id) > 2;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35823/7

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g its a simple table structure with two columns content_id and geography_id, what exactly I want to achieve is fetch all these content ids that are tagged to only one value of geography id (i.e. geography id is 126) and none other.

Comment: Hi, actually I am looking for all those content ids that have to be tagged to geography_id = 11 and 12 but the result can also include the content ids that are tagged to more geographies other than 11 and 12.Being tagged to only those two geographies is not the critria.

Comment: @user972418: I gave you the solution for all of them

Comment: I just checked sqlfiddle.com/#!12/35f6a/2 but as said above I am looking for content ids that are definitely tagged to geo 11 and 12. It's ok if that includes content ids tagged to other geos beside 11 and 12.

Comment: @user972418: my second statement does that. The SQLFiddle you mention was for Manvendra to show him that his statement was **wrong**. Please use the fiddle in my *answer*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I have got my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty straight forward. You just need to group the records by `content_ID` and count the number of `geography_id` (*should be equal to one*).

```
SELECT  content_ID
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY content_ID
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT geography_id) = 1 AND
        MAX(geography_id) = 'specific tag'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more query. How do I fetch all those content ids that are essentially tagged to geography ids 11 and 12. It may also include the rows that are tagged to any other geography id as well.

Comment: Try this, **WHERE GEOGRAPHY_ID IN (11,12) GROUP BY CONTENT_ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 2**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe i misunderstand but the op says in the comment that it may include rows that are taggedto any other geographic id..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name don't be sory, we don't know yet if this is correct :) you have also an excellent answer. :)

Comment: I can't hardy update my answer since im in mobile now.. See my previous comment :)

Comment: Hi, actually I am looking for all those content ids that have to be tagged to geography_id = 11 and 12 but the result can also include the content ids that are tagged to more geographies other than 11 and 12.Being tagged to only those two geographies is not the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

@a_horse_with_no_name you are right, my answer was wrong.

Correct answer is

```
SELECT content_id
from TableName
where content_id in (
SELECT  content_ID
FROM    TableName
WHERE   geography_id in (11)
)
group by content_id
having count(distinct geography_id)=1
```

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g its a simple table structure with two columns content_id and geography_id, what exactly I want to achieve is fetch all these content ids that are tagged to only one value of geography id (i.e. geography id is 126) and none other.

Comment: That won't work. It will also return content_id's that have more than just that one specific geography_id. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/35f6a/2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more query. How do I fetch all those content ids that are essentially tagged to geography ids 11 and 12. It may also include the rows that are tagged to any other geography id as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean only non repeating contentId then

```
select contentid
from mytable
group by contentid
having count(*)=1
```

This will return those contentIds that are mapped to only one geoghraphyId.

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/193c3/1)**

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g its a simple table structure with two columns content_id and geography_id, what exactly I want to achieve is fetch all these content ids that are tagged to only one value of geography id (i.e. geography id is 126) and none other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more query. How do I fetch all those content ids that are essentially tagged to geography ids 11 and 12. It may also include the rows that are tagged to any other geography id as well.